# How to handle a failed or significantly delayed webhook?

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, webhooks, amazon-sqs

We have a middleware that depends on another system to execute payment requests. This third-party system usually sends a webhook later when a payment request is performed from our end and successfully done at their end after processing. **Sometimes they failed or significantly delayed** sending webhook and **there is no retry mechanism** at their end. However, they have **a status query API** at their end to know the current status of the payment request.

**We update our payment status based on this webhook and this is very vital for our system.** Now for the use case, we have found two ways to handle this failed webhook

1. Run a scheduler to cater failed webhook requests and check with their status query API
2. Implement a Queue, where a new entry will be added to the queue when an original payment request took place and fire status query API Using Time-out events eg. SQS.

The above way around has its own pros and cons. **Is there any other way around to handle this use case?** **If no, which one of two would be the best choice.**

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an orchestrator like [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) to implement your business logic. The code to act on the webhook as well as poll the status API in parallel would be pretty simple.